# Backbone urls to Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

I have a Backbone on Rails app that contains `task_list` and `project` models. A task list has a `project_id` column that refers to the project it belongs to.

In Rails, I set the routes for the task lists are the following:

```
POST    /projects/:project_id/task_lists   task_lists#create  
PUT     /task_lists/:id(.:format)          task_lists#update  
DELETE  /task_lists/:id(.:format)          task_lists#destroy
```

Upon creating a task list, what I'm doing in Backbone is instantiating the task list, setting the url for the `task_lists#create` route in Rails, and then saving it to the server:

```
taskList = new App.Models.TaskLists(data);  
taskList.url = "/projects/" + current_project_id + "/task_lists";  
taskList.save();
```

I do the same above when I need to update or delete a task list, only that the url is set to `"task_lists/" + this.id`.

How I can setup my `models/taskList.js` file in Backbone without having to specify the URLs every time I need to CRUD a task list? I know I have to use a custom function, `url: function () {...}`, but Backbone seems to use `model.url` instead of `model.url()` upon passing data back to the Rails server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Model.url()` is a function http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-65 so expand from [@redconservatory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18905531/832759) answer:

```
initialize: function(attrs, options){
    // pass in the actual project model instead
    this.project = options.project;
},
url: function () {
    // keep the backbone default stuffs so specifying urlRoot will still work
    var base = _.result(this, 'urlRoot') || _.result(this.collection, 'url') || urlError();
    // you only need project url when the object is new so this is enough
    if (this.isNew()) return project.url + base;
    return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) === '/' ? '' : '/') + encodeURIComponent(this.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the id when you initialize your collection as part of the "options" object (the second argument.

The first argument is models, which in the example below is empty (as in [ ]).

When the object "c" is created, the initialize method is immediately called, and you can do stuff with the options as shown below:

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(models, options) {
        this.current_project_id = options.current_project_id;
    },
    url: function() {
        return "/projects/" + this.current_project_id + "/task_lists"; 
    }
});

var c = new MyCollection([  ], { current_project_id: 2 } );
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnf8B/264/)